# Visible surface in some angle in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have surface of floor like in screenshot http://prntscr.com/amqstw. If I move camera in some angle I don`t see angle floor : http://prntscr.com/amqt19. How I may resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That effect is due to backface culling. 
In that angle (probably) the camera is inside the mesh of the floor, so the normal vectors of the cube (I presume) are facing the other way, and they get "culled" (become invisible).
You can turn it of in two ways:

- By editing the mesh in your modeling software so that it becomes a
  "double-sided mesh", or
- By finding a shader online which, once
  applied to the floor object, deactivates its backfire culling (harder
  to do, without screwing up something else)